# Отключение кнопки WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть некоторая кнопка, которая создана от класса UserControl(то есть является не стандартной). И мне нужно, что бы когда свойство этой кнопки `IsEnabled = false`, то она становилась серой. (Кнопка сделана через Path)

Как я пытался решить эту проблему:

1. Делал анимацию для кнопки. Но серый цвет проскакивает только на секунду, но при этом `IsEnabled = false`(по идеи кнопка должна оставаться серой);
2. Потом решил сделать через стиль с триггерами:

XAML:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="en">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Но при таком подходе IsEnabled и Fill - "Не распознан или не доступен"

3. Попытался прописать Style прям в Path, но все безуспешно...

Уже более близок к ответу. Сделал ресурс таким образом

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="en" TargetType="Path">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Но серый цвет все равно проскакивает на короткое время.

Comment: А вы от `Button` унаследоваться не забыли?

Comment: @Bulson. Не могу понять при чем тут Button? И как я могу унаследоваться сразу от двух классов? Моя типа "кнопка" не является "кнопкой" я создавал ее через "Пользовательский элемент управления"..

Comment: Да, я невнимательно прочитал, подумал про `CustomControl`

Answer (score 1):

А почему `Fill` (`<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>`)?

Я бы сделал `<Setter Property="Background " Value="Gray"/>`

То есть, если кнопка выключена то фон кнопки станет серым.

Если что будет хелпой для других (просто увидел год и понял что не актуально)

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
<Style x:Key="en" TargetType="Button">
    ...
```

?

Comment: Теперь IsEnabled видит, но не Fill

Comment: @batya: А, и правда. А покажите ваш `Button` и его `Path`.

Comment: Я уже сделал. Правда скорее всего через костыли. Теперь когда у меня IsEnabled = false, просто отключается анимация. Так как проблема была в том, что серый цвет устанавливался, но срабатывало событие "MouseOver..." и цвет опять устанавливался в начальный(желтый).

Comment: @batya: А вы всё же выложите код, а вдруг можно будет сделать простое решение. Анимация по идее вообще не нужна?

Comment: тогда уже завтра. Так как на сегодня с меня хватит...